# Child Theme: how to override variables?

Tags: templates, feed, child-theme

I'm going to build my first Child Theme. I understood how to override functions (hope!), but how to override variables?
For example, in a Premium Template I want to change the values of feed variables shown in functions.php:

```
$app_rss_feed = 'http://xxx.rss';
$app_twitter_rss_feed = 'http://yyy.rss';
$app_forum_rss_feed = 'http://zzz.rss';
```

But if I create my functions.php file inside my child theme and assign a different RSS feed value to these variables... nothing happens.
So, which is the right way to change variables?

Comment: are those variables inside a function?

Comment: the variables are outside any function. Are declared inside the functions.php of the theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm mobile, so this will be short.

Use the after_setup_theme hook to add a function to set those variables. Declare them as global inside that function before setting them.

Hope that helps.

If anybody wants to add an example to this answer before I get home, feel free. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've done as you suggested and it works: function the_theme_setup(){    global $app_rss_feed, $app_twitter_rss_feed, $app_forum_rss_feed;    $app_rss_feed = 'http://xxx.rss'
    $app_twitter_rss_feed = 'http://yyy.rss' $app_forum_rss_feed = 'http://zzz.rss' }    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'the_theme_setup' ); Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The parent theme’s `functions.php` is loaded later, it will overwrite those variables. Show us the code where these variables are declared and where thex are used, there may be a filter you could use.

An example: In `fetch_feed()` you can filter the feed URL:

```
do_action_ref_array( 'wp_feed_options', array( &$feed, $url ) );
```

To filter the values, you could check for the parent theme’s URL:

```
add_filter( 'wp_feed_options', 'wpse_46644_feed' );

function wpse_46644_feed( $arr )
{
    if ( 'http://example.com/feed/' === $arr[1] )
    {
        $arr[0]->set_feed_url( 'http://replacement.example.com/feed/' );
    }
}
```

*Not tested, just an idea.*